# Diff between constant and variable

Tags: programming-languages

What exactly is the difference between a constant and a variable. Can constants be understood as  values that can be assigned to variables in a program

Comment: The specifics of this would depend on the language being used.

Comment: Please mention the language you are using.

Comment: I'd say, whatever language, the difference is that a constant is constant (its value doesn't change) whereas a variable is variable (its value can change). You may use a constant pi in your program (which is fixed 3.1415...) and a variable radius (which you calculate or get from somewhere).

Comment: @ThorstenKettner There are plenty of languages where the term "constant" is used for variables that can't be re-assigned, so something like `const int r = calculateRadius();` would be perfectly valid there. So it does depend on the language.

Comment: @sepp2k in what sense is 'r' therefore a variable?

Comment: @another-dave I'm saying that `r` is a constant in the terms of those languages. Thorsten was saying that it's not a constant (regardless of the language) because its value depends on `calculateRadius()` whose value may in turn depend on variables, IO or other non-constant factors.

Comment: And therefore it is not a 'variable'.  It has a value that does not vary.  Not every named value is a 'variable' and not every named value even needs an assigned storage location. (Obligatory shout-out to Algol68 here, which was careful about such matters)

Answer (score 1):

You basically have the right idea. The correct idea is a bit hard to give with the small amount of information you give in your question.

"constant" is a bit vague. The name is used to refer to literals, symbolic constants, constant expressions, immutable variables ...

Anyway, the answer depends strongly on what language you're using and what context you've heard the term "constant" in.

For example, in the C programming language, most symbolic constants do not exist at runtime. They are simply names that are replaced by their actual literal values as the first step before compilation.

In other languages, constants are named variables that are saved into the built program that contain a value that can't be changed, and can be listed or so.

Wait, constants are sometimes variables?

Well, the terms "constant" and "variable" are kind of vague concepts that are sometimes used wrongly, and don't have a straight translation into machine code.

At the core, there is just memory. And memory contains data. Constants are usually parts of the memory that are just loaded from disk for you by the operating system together with your compiled code, and then your code can read them. Variables are parts of the memory for which "gaps" in memory are set aside by the system, and then your code can put values into it or read it.

That's why it's a bit hard to offer a concise definition of a variable and a constant. It depends on what level of the computer you are looking at it, through which language.

In most languages, a symbolic constant is simply a more convenient name you can use in your code to refer to a fixed number or other literal value. A name whose value you can change in one central location before you compile your code, and all other places that use the symbolic name automatically pick up the value.

Variables are boxes into which you can put any value.

So you're basically right. But there can be more to the story depending on what language you're using.

The reason for symbolic constants is mostly to make your code more readable. Instead of

```
leftCoordinate = 16 + 20 + 4
```

you can write

```
leftCoordinate = LEFT_MARGIN + SIDEBAR_WIDTH + LINE_WIDTH
```

and suddenly it is much more obvious which of these numbers you have to change to change the right part. Also, you can use them to make sure two numbers always match. Like, elsewhere in your program, you may have the code that draws the "line" mentioned above, and just do

```
setLineWidth(LINE_WIDTH)
drawLine(LEFT_MARGIN + SIDEBAR_WIDTH, 0, LEFT_MARGIN + SIDEBAR_WIDTH, 100)
```

And if you ever decide you want a thinner line, you just change the constant's value, and *all* your code magically updates, and you just need to recompile.